# The Reuse/Release Equivalence Principle (REP)

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

What is the Reuse/Release Equivalence Principle and why is it important?

Comment: Guess you want the self-learner badge :-)

Comment: Well, that would be nice. But the main reason I'm doing this (and asking the other questions about OO design principles) is to help seed the site with information and hopefully increase awareness of these principles. I'm constantly shocked at the number of devs I meet who have never heard of them.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I deleted my answer chastising you for going down the list. (It should have been a comment here anyway.)

Comment: Cheers. What do you think is the best way to seed information like this? Immediately answer the question myself (which seems to discourage others from contributing or even viewing, as here), or just let the community respond to it (which seems to generate more views and replies)?

Answer (score 41):

The Reuse/Release Equivalence Principle (REP) says:

> The unit of reuse is the unit of release. Effective reuse requires tracking of releases from a change control system. The package is the effective unit of reuse and release.

**The unit of reuse is the unit of release**

Code should not be reused by copying it from one class and pasting it into another. If the original author fixes any bugs in the code, or adds any features, you will not automatically get the benefit. You will have to find out what's changed, then alter your copy. Your code and the original code will gradually diverge.

Instead, code should be reused by including a released library in your code. The original author retains responsibility for maintaining it; you should not even need to see the source code.

**Effective reuse requires tracking of releases from a change control system**

The author of a library needs to identify releases with numbers or names of some sort. This allows users of the library to identify different versions. This requires the use of some kind of release tracking system.

**The package is the effective unit of reuse and release**

It might be possible to use a class as the unit of reuse and release, however there are so many classes in a typical application, it would be burdensome for the release tracking system to keep track of them all. A larger-scale entity is required, and the package fits this need well.

See also Robert Martin's article on [Granularity](https://web.archive.org/web/20030614000424/http://objectmentor.com/resources/articles/granularity.pdf).

Comment: By package, I guess what is meant is *not* Java package or C# namespace, but dll and jar. Is that right?

Comment: That link to Granularity is no longer working. Is it here https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/53d0/8de266fb80355400d10f7ea77eea971d48f9.pdf?

Comment: That link is also dead.

Comment: Robert Martin's article on Granularity link: http://docs.google.com/a/cleancoder.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0BwhCYaYDn8EgOGM2ZGFhNmYtNmE4ZS00OGY5LWFkZTYtMjE0ZGNjODQ0MjEx&hl=en
(found at http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod)

Comment: @LaurentBourgault-Roy I suppose also artifact could be use to keep it more generic

Answer (score 2):

From Clean Architecture, by Robert Martin.

> The Reuse/Release Equivalence Principle (REP) is a principle that seems
>   obvious, at least in hindsight. People who want to reuse software components
>   cannot, and will not, do so unless those components are tracked through a
>   release process and are given release numbers.
>
> This is not simply because, without release numbers, there would be no way to
>   ensure that all the reused components are compatible with each other. Rather, it
>   also reflects the fact that software developers need to know when new releases
>   are coming, and which changes those new releases will bring.
>
> It is not uncommon for developers to be alerted about a new release and decide,
>   based on the changes made in that release, to continue to use the old release
>   instead. Therefore the release process must produce the appropriate notifications
>   and release documentation so that users can make informed decisions about
>   when and whether to integrate the new release.

Comment: If the principle is that people will only used properly tracked components, why do they call it the Reuse/Release Equivalence Principle. What's equivalent to what?

Comment: The unit of reuse is defined by the unit of release. You shall not use a single class from a release and add dependency tracking to changes of that class. Rather you depend on the whole package by its released version. Same is, that you are not encouraged to use SNAPSHOT releases. The very common "[1.5.*)"  version pattern also is a smell in regard to this pattern. While you still use a released package for reuse, you cannot guarantee, that you use the same version in two builds. Instead, use the exact version number to fulfill the reuse.